# Django: Filter data between to dates | DatetimeField received a naive datetime

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-orm

I *simply* want to filter my records between two dates.

Let's say there is a record table `Measurements` that has the property `timestamp`:

```
class Measurements(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
```

When I checked the `timestamp` of the last record `Measurements.objects.last().timestamp` it returns:

```
datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 13, 6, 29, 48, 90138, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Now I want to filter the data between to dates `from_date` and `to_date`. According to previous questions about this issue, I used `make_aware`. For testing I used `count` to get the amount of entries.

```
from .models import *
from datetime import datetime
from django.utils.timezone import make_aware

def get_measurements(request):
    from_date = make_aware(datetime(2020, 10, 12, 15, 30, 0, 0))
    to_date = make_aware(datetime(2020, 10, 12, 16, 0, 0, 0))
    print(from_date)
    print(to_date)

    measurements = DriveMeasurements.objects.filter(
        plc_timestamp__range=["2020-01-01", "2020-01-31"])
    print(measurements.count())
```

When printing the two dates in my shell, it returns:

```
datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 12, 15, 30, tzinfo=<UTC>)
datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 12, 16, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

When I run the function above, Django fires the following message:

**RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Measurements.timestamp received a naive datetime (2020-01-31 00:00:00) while time zone support is active.
warnings.warn("DateTimeField %s received a naive datetime (%s)"**

The print statement `print(measurements.count())` prints `0` but there are ~ 18000 records in the database.

So why is the filter not working and the Django message thrown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed correct that you make the `from_date` and `to_date` aware, but you do not use that in the `__range` check. You should work with:

```
def get_measurements(request):
    from_date = make_aware(datetime(2020, 10, 12, 15, 30, 0, 0))
    to_date = make_aware(datetime(2020, 10, 12, 16, 0, 0, 0))
    print(from_date)
    print(to_date)

    measurements = DriveMeasurements.objects.filter(
        #  use timezone aware datetimes ↓
        plc_timestamp__range=(from_date, to_date)
    )
    print(measurements.count())
```

Comment: OMG, too focused on the dates above that I did not notice that my hardcoded dates where still in there. Thank you!